# How to create python kafka producer with multiple bootstrap servers?

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I'm trying to use send messages to a Kafka topic which is supported by multiple brokers. Below is my method, where `self.bootstrap_servers = "[b-1.dev-stg-kafka.wjiw3s.c1.kafka.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:9092, b-2.dev-stg-kafka.wjiw3s.c1.kafka.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:9092]"`

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
from time import sleep
    def send(self):
        try:
            producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=self.bootstrap_server, api_version=(0, 10, 1))
            message = self.prepare_message()
            producer.send(self.topic, self.encoded_payload)
            sleep(2)
        except:
            print("Exception sending message to kafka")
```

when I try to test this I get in the exception block and the line that fails is when I create my producer. How can I publish a Kafka message with this KafkaProducer, which has multiple kafka bootstrap_servers supporting it? Is there another way to do this?

Error:

```
  File "C:\Users\ENV\datareplayer\venv\lib\site-packages\kafka\client_async.py", line 216, in __init__
    self._bootstrap(collect_hosts(self.config['bootstrap_servers']))
  File "C:\Users\ENV\datareplayer\venv\lib\site-packages\kafka\conn.py", line 1236, in collect_hosts
    host, port, afi = get_ip_port_afi(host_port)
  File "C:\Users\ENV\datareplayer\venv\lib\site-packages\kafka\conn.py", line 1192, in get_ip_port_afi
    host, rest = host_and_port_str[1:].split(']')
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: Why did you think you needed square brackets? That's not in any of the examples

Comment: The examples I found were with square brackets. Should it just be a string for the bootstrap_server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just try to sepaprate servers by comma. It works.

```
kafka_servers = ["localhost:9092","localhost:9093","localhost:9094"]

producer = KafkaProducer(
    bootstrap_servers = kafka_servers, 
    value_serializer=json_serializer
)
consumer = KafkaConsumer( 
     "topic_name",
     bootstrap_servers=["localhost:9092","localhost:9093","localhost:9094"],
     auto_offset_reset="earliest", 
     group_id="consumer-group-a"
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Regarding sending data to kafka cluster with multiple brokers,
The bootstrap server is just the initial connection point, it gets from the bootstraping server metadata where the data leaders are and connects to the appropriate brokers... so you will need a network connection to all brokers in the cluster and it is does not matter which broker is chosen as the bootstrap server

Being said that... the recommended way is to have comma separated list as bootstrap servers, so if one is down it will use the next in the list...

Regarding specifying list of bootstrap servers in the setting of the python kafka

Which python kafka libraries are you using?

It seems there is open issue regarding this matter that had not been fixed yet.

https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/issues/711

> Description
> The configuration key bootstrap.servers implies that multiple servers can be specified, but it is not explicitly defined what this key's value should be. It appears that only a string using comma separation is allowed for this config key. If a Python list is given, no explicit error or feedback is given to indicate this is not valid. Instead, calls to consumer.poll() or other broker-bound functions simply block and never succeed.

> Ideally, a Python list (e.g. ["broker1", "broker2"]) should be valid; or at the very least, constructing the Consumer should throw a runtime/configuration exception.

Comment: OP appears to be using `kafka-python`

Comment: Yes, I'm using `kafka-python`

Comment: Try to remove the space between the list elements and check again

Comment: self.bootstrap_servers = ['b-1.dev-stg-kafka.wjiw3s.c1.kafka.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:9092', 'b-2.dev-stg-kafka.wjiw3s.c1.kafka.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:9092']

Answer (score 1):

`ast.literal_eval(bootstrap_servers)` can help.

It takes a stringified list as input, and converts it to a list. For example:

```
input_str = "['broker1', 'broker2', 'broker3']"

type(input_str)
str
```

If you do

```
input_list = ast.literal_eval(input_str)
```

`input_list` is now a list

```
type(input_list)
list
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).